# Drawing crown image over king checkers?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making a website where users can play checkers both online and locally.

I am currently trying to draw crowns over the checkers that are crowned. Here is my checker class where I am trying to draw the crown if the checker is a king:

```
function Checker(x,y,color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.color = color;
    this.king = false;

    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.ellipse(this.x+32,this.y+32,28,28,45 * Math.PI/180,0,2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        if(this.king) {
            crown.onload = function() {ctx.drawImage(crown,this.x,this.y)};
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my entire code: (I made a JSFiddle :) )
https://jsfiddle.net/yv0v1auz/

For some reason the crowns do not draw on top of the checker?

Why is this? Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem, I changed line 365 from this:

```
crown.onload = function() {ctx.drawImage(crown,this.x,this.y)};
```

to this:

```
ctx.drawImage(crown,this.x,this.y);
```

I then moved line 131 to line 84. This seemed to fix my problem

The problem seemed to be that I had the picture in the wrong directory (whoops)
Then, the checker's king status would only update when it was clicked. That being why the image would not appear unless it was selected. That is why I moved line 131 to line 84.